# How to fiill Na value in dataframe by get from another rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with follow columns, "Street", "State", "Country", "Zip Code"
and some NaN values in rows.
the result of this expression `df['Street'].isna().sum()` is `31`, but this `df['State'].isna().sum()`  is `204`, and by analogy with the rest of data.
How there can be seen number of rows of "Street" column with Nan values are less than others.

I want to iterate all dataframe by state, country and zip code, and if I meet Nan value I will find if there exists another row with the same street and fill instead of Nan value the zip/Country/State value of matching street.

```
count = 0
for street, city, state, zip_code in zip(df['Street'], df['City'], df['State'], df['Zip Code']):

  if df['City'][count].isna():
    location = get_matches(street, df['Street'], df['City'])
    if location != None:
      df['City'][count] = location

  if df['State'][count].isna():
    location = get_matches(street, df['Street'], df['State'])
    if location != None:
      df['State'][count] = location

  if df['Zip Code'][count].isna():
    location = get_matches(street, df['Street'], df['Zip Code'])
    if location != None:
      df['Zip Code'][count] = location

  count = count + 1

def get_matches(adress,df_street, df_location):
  for street, location in zip(df_street, df_location):
    if street == adress:
      return location
```

This is my code, but it doesen't work properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the __provided__ data. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

better use .fillna(value) instead of .isna()

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html